# ISSUE: Attempt to present whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Hi i keep getting whose view is not in the window hierarchy error whenever the time exceeded and goes back to the start screen when detect inacitivity of the application. How do i encounter this error? It keep appearing on my output whenever the time exceeded but it doesnt affect my application at all.

This is the error:

2015-08-19 15:42:33.237 DigitalFeedback[8545:637565] Warning: Attempt to present StartUpViewController: 0x155e4800> on CEOMsgViewController: 0x156d4050> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

This is my code:

```
 (void)resetIdleTimer {

    if (!idleTimer) {
        idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kMaxIdleTimeSeconds
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
    }
    else {
        if (fabs([idleTimer.fireDate timeIntervalSinceNow]) < kMaxIdleTimeSeconds-1.0) {
            [idleTimer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:kMaxIdleTimeSeconds]];
        }
    }
}

 (void)idleTimerExceeded {
    //[idleTimer release];
    idleTimer = nil;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BackToStartUpSegue" sender:self];
    [self resetIdleTimer];
}

 (UIResponder *)nextResponder {
    [self resetIdleTimer];
    return [super nextResponder];
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `present`, or have a segue that is modal?

Comment: @wain its a segue modal. im trying to return to first screen which is @"BackToStartUpSegue"

Comment: And is this controller actually on screen when its timer expires?